# ERRO[0003] ERROR: relation "public.databases" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am using gorm (Golang) to connect to my postgres database below the connection code

```
func NewDatabase(config *config.Config) *gorm.DB {
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf(
        "host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable",
        config.DBHost, config.DBUser, config.DBPass, config.DBName, config.DBPort)
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            TablePrefix:   "public.",
            SingularTable: false,
            NameReplacer: CustomReplacer{func(s string) string {
                return strings.NewReplacer("\"", "").Replace(s)
            }},
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal("Error connecting to database ", err)
    }
    logrus.Info("Database connection successful")

    sqlDB, err := db.DB()

    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal("Error getting sql connection", err)
    }

    sqlDB.SetMaxIdleConns(config.DBMaxIdlePoolSize)
    sqlDB.SetMaxOpenConns(config.DBMaxOpenPoolSize)
    return db
}
```

I am getting unusual error `ERRO[0003] ERROR: relation "public.databases" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)` because databases table exists in my database in the public schema.

However if I point the database to a remote DB which has same data as local it works perfectly fine.

Comment: If you are able to connect to the target database using `psql` and you do see the table `databases` there, then that suggests that your Go program is NOT connected to that same database. This could be caused by misconfiguring `config.DBName`. To find out what database you are **actually** connected to, simply run `select current_database();` using the `sqlDB` handle. You can also run `select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public';` to get a list of tables accessible through that same `sqlDB` handle.

Answer (score 0):

Add `search_path=public` parameter to the connection string.